# Error in integrating inmobi sdk in main.xml

Tags: android, xml, inmobi

here is my xml error report

```
    The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.inmobi.androidsdk.IMAdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse
```

and code of main.xml is like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<com.inmobi.androidsdk.IMAdView
    android:id="@+id/imAdview"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    adSize="15"
    appId="a521d7b121144753a4709e018826c487" />
```

Didn't get issue here ,why i am getting this error ,suggest some solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code in your xml

`<com.inmobi.monetization.IMBanner android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="50dp" android:id="@+id/banner"
adSize="15" appId="YOUR-APP-ID" />`

The code you are using is from the old integration guidelines. This will not work for the latest InMobi sdk. For more details please check https://www.inmobi.com/support/integration/23817448/22051163/android-sdk-integration-guide/